# Scrapy not scraping all results

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I want to scrape the NHL match data. Then, two rows must be scraped per a match(a url). When I scrape one match(one url), result is not empty. But when I scrape ten matches, result is empty, ex)scraped 16 of 20.

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import time
from nhl.items import NHLItem


class NHL_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='NHL'
    allowed_domains=["nhl.com"]
    start_urls=["https://www.nhl.com/gamecenter/20180%d"%i for i in range(20001,20011)]
    

    def __init__(self):
        scrapy.Spider.__init__(self)
        self.browser=webdriver.Chrome("/users/박정균/chromedriver")

    
    def parse(self,response):
        self.browser.get(response.url)   
        
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gamecenter-index-component__app"]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/nav/ul/li[2]/a').click()
        
        source=self.browser.page_source
        html=self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*').get_attribute('outerHTML')
        selector=Selector(text=html)
        
        rows = selector.xpath('//*[@class="statistics__season-stats"]/table/tbody/tr')
        
        
        for row in rows:
            item=NHLItem()
            item["Team"]=row.xpath('.//*[@class="media-heading small"]/text()')[0].extract()
            item["Shots"]=row.xpath('./td[2]/text()')[0].extract()
            item["FO"]=row.xpath('./td[3]/text()')[0].extract()
            item["PP"]=row.xpath('./td[4]/text()')[0].extract()
            yield item
```

DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET [https://www.nhl.com/gamecenter/wsh-vs-pit/2018/10/04/2018020007>](https://www.nhl.com/gamecenter/wsh-vs-pit/2018/10/04/2018020007%3E) (referer: None)

This is cmd result.

csv ex) wsh,30,15%
pit,42,40%   <-----this is my wish

```
    wsh,30,15%
    (empty)      <-----this is my result
```

Comment: You will need to do some debugging yourself. Firstly, after the line `html=self.browser...` you need to print out `html` to see if you got any results. The page is loaded with Javascript, and your Selenium click does not have an additional wait. So it is possible that the HTML does not yet contain what you are looking for. Once you are sure `html` contains the correct data, then update the question if you have specific problems. I checked and your XPath is correct when the HTML is there. So I think the problem is that step where you pass HTML from Selenium to Scrapy.

Comment: Also, rather use `.get()` instead of `[0].extract()`. It is simpler and won't give an index error if nothing is found.

Comment: If `html` does contain something, also print out `rows` to see if it found any rows.